# Android Volley JsonObject put process

Tags: android, json

pull the data in the database textview
want to print. but values come in null.
Is there an error in request processing? or how should the request process be?
Is there an error in php?
Below is my android and php code.

```
    userTc = findViewById(R.id.tc_no);
    userName = findViewById(R.id.name);
    userSurname = findViewById(R.id.surname);
    userType = findViewById(R.id.type);

    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("tc",userTc);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String url = "http:/database/show.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, jsonObject, new 
    Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        userTc.setText(response.getString("tc"));
                        userName.setText(response.getString("name"));
                        userSurname.setText(response.getString("surname"));
                        userType.setText(response.getString("type"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + error, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });{

    }








    $tc=$_GET["tc"];
    $sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT tc,name,surname,type FROM personel");
    $sql->execute();
    $fetch=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode(array("tc"=>$fetch["tc"],"name"=>$fetch["name"],"surname"=>$fetch["surname"],"type"=>$fetch["type"]));
```

Comment: check your url `final String url = "http://database/show.php";`

Comment: I didn't want to give it all for security.Is there an error or missing place in the  request process?

Comment: Yes I know. I dont need what is your real API or Service too, sorry I mean use `final String url = "http://database/show.php";` instead `final String url = "http:/database/show.php";`

Comment: i am sorry i can't do anything